# Create a custom authentication

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm transferring a database to a new project and more precisely the users.
Don't ask me why but the passwords in the old database were hashed with md5 and then with sha256.

I'm using **django-rest-auth** to manage login.

```
url(r'^api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
```

I added a custom authentication method:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
     'users.auth.OldCustomAuthentication',
     'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
  )
}
```

Here is my auth file:

```
class OldCustomAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        try:
            password = request.POST['password']
            email = request.POST['email']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            return None

        if not password or not email:
            return None

        password = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
        password = hashlib.sha256(password.hexdigest().encode())

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password.hexdigest())
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        # User is found every time
        print('FOUND USER', user)
        return user, None
```

But I still get an error when I request http://apiUrl/rest-auth/login/:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea? Or maybe I'm doing it in a wrong way.

Thank you in advance.

Jeremy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is salt used when hashing. Here is the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/ so its not just hash of password.

Comment: Does your return line need to be a tuple instead of two variables? Documentation for reference (see code sample): https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#example

Comment: The thing is I find my user in my new database. I just want to know what I need to return to say "Hey, you're connected". I thought returning  **user, None** would let django-rest-framework know that this user used the good credentials.
And @MrName, with or without parenthesis, it's the same

Comment: Have tried to remove JSONWebTokenAuthentication to see if it works this way?

Comment: Yes, and I still have the same response from the endpoint **/rest-auth/login/** ...
You can see a screenshot of the debugger here: https://imgur.com/a/uhzqM2a

Comment: Does the 'django-rest-auth' package allow for overriding authentication classes? Nothing in the docs seems to indicate that it does, and the error message you are seeing is bubbling up from the serializer in that package I believe.

Comment: Well, that's true. But because the 'django-rest-auth' is highly-coupled with django-rest-framework, I thought I could achieve it like this.
And anyway my function is called every time I try to use the login endpoint. (So I guess that's the a way to do it)
But if you have a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, I'm listening!

Comment: My guess would be that your code is working just fine, and then the serializer from django-rest-auth is hitting after that, producing the error you see. If this is correct (the debugger would help here), try providing a custom serializer (https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) and overriding the validate method (https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L62).

Comment: Thank you so much!
So I created a new serializer and put inside the logic I had in my **OldCustomAuthentiction** class. I answered to the post.  If you see things to correct let me know so I can correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice of [@MrName](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366989/mrname) I managed to solve my issue.

So I deleted **DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES** in my settings and added this:

```
 REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'users.auth.LoginSerializer'
 }
```

Then I copy pasted the [original serializer](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L19) and modified the function _validate_email with:

```
def _validate_email(self, email, password):
    user = None

    if email and password:
        user = self.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        # TODO: REMOVE ONCE ALL USERS HAVE BEEN TRANSFERED TO THE NEW SYSTEM
        if user is None:
            password_hashed = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
            password_hashed = hashlib.sha256(password_hashed.hexdigest().encode())
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password_hashed.hexdigest())
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                user = None
    else:
        msg = _('Must include "email" and "password".')
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

    return user
```